# Javascript object counter not incrementing as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting the `errorCount` property to increase during code execution. The problem I am having is occurring inside of the `$.ajax` request, more specifically the `addError()` method.

If I use the following code below to check the current count of `errorCount` it always returns `0` even though I have manually created an error to occur. But inside of the ajax method after I call `addError()` and then check the value of `errorCount` it shows `1` like it should. What did I do wrong?

```
var boom = new test(settings, formData, search);
console.log(boom.errorCount);
boom.queueCalls(settings);
console.log(boom);
console.log(boom.errorCount);
```

Here is the object code:

```
function test(a, b, c) {
    this.settings = a;
    this.formData = b;
    this.search = c;
    this.errorCount = 0;
}

test.prototype = {
    constructor: test,
    queueEmails:function(settings, formData, search) {
        var url = '/example-url-endpoint';
        var data = {postData: settings + "&" + formData + "&" + search};
        this.sendRequest(url, data);
    },
    queueCalls:function(settings) {
        var url = '/example-url-endpoint2';
        this.sendRequest(url, settings);
    },
    addMessage:function(response) {
        flashMessage(response.Message, response.Result);
    },
    addError:function() {
        this.errorCount++;
    },
    sendRequest:function(url, data) {
        var blah = this;

        j$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                response = JSON.parse(data);
                if(response.Result != 'error') {
                    blah.addMessage(response);
                } else {
                    blah.addMessage(response);
                    blah.addError();
                    console.log(blah.errorCount);
                }
            },
            error: function(e, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                blah.addError();
                console.log(blah.errorCount);
                alert("There was an error creating the queue");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because the call is asynchronous, it shows 0 before the error returns 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are doing an asynchronous (AJAX) call. When you call the queueCalls function, it makes the AJAX call, then runs your console.log statements. It does not wait until the AJAX call is done, and you have received your errors to run the console statements. If you want to do that, look at the [jQuery documentation for .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), and either make your AJAX call not asynchronous, or put your console statements in a .done() event handler that will fire after the AJAX call is complete.

[image]